# What are notations to express uniqueness in formulae and diagrams?

Tags: logic, notation, category-theory

I am familiar with the notation $\exists\,!$ to express both existence and uniqueness.  For example $$\;\;\exists\,!x\!:\!P\,(x)\;\;$$ means "there exists a unique $x$ such that $P\,(x)$ holds", for some predicate $P\,$.

> Is there some similarly compact notation to denote *only* uniqueness (i.e. without simultaneously asserting existence)?

In other words, is there a similarly compact, "easy-to-parse" way to express the assertion "$P\,(x)$ holds for at most one $x$"?<sup>*</sup>

There is a somewhat analogous question for category-theoretic diagrams.  I have seen the convention of using a dashed (or dotted) arrow to indicate the universality of the corresponding morphism (see, for example, [*Algebra*](http://books.google.com/books?id=piwKmqalFswC) by Mac Lane and Birkhoff).  Some authors extend this convention to indicate existence-and-uniqueness (e.g. see Turi's [*Category Theory Lecture Notes*](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/dt/CT/categories.pdf)).  Hence, I see the dashed arrow as the "diagrammatic cousin" of $\exists\,!\,$.  Now, suppose we are making some diagram $\mathcal{D}$ featuring objects $A$ and $B$, say.

> Is there some convention to *graphically* represent the assertion "there is at most one morphism $\alpha$ from $A$ to $B$ [such that diagram $\mathcal{D}$ commutes]"?

Thanks!

*<sub>Of course, the immediate guess ("back-forming" from $\exists\,!$) is that the lone $!$ serves this purpose.  Thus the assertion above would be expressed with $$!\, x\!:\!P\,(x).$$  I see no immediate problems with using $!$ for this purpose (with the possible exception of cases where the context includes many factorials) but I have never seen such usage, and I would prefer to adopt a notation that has at least some currency, even if it does not complement the $\exists\,!$ form as nicely as $!$ does.</sub>

Comment: Why use a notation, which is likely to be cryptic if it is not standard, when words will be more pleasant to read and more precise in meaning?

Comment: Sorry, I beg to differ.  At any rate, this is a matter of taste, and I would not like to take the conversation in that direction; for those who prefer to avoid notation, my question is of little interest.

Comment: I have not seen hypercompact notation for "there is at most one $x$" in research papers in logic, or indeed anywhere else.

Comment: In some programming languages `!=` is used for negation of being equal. Hence you can misfire as saying "there does not exist ...." Besides, you are doing nothing but an overload of the readers *temporary mental capacity* by writing quite definite concepts by ambiguous notation which can be described by exactly one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\exists^{=n}_xP(x)$ might be useful for you, that means that there exists exactly $n$ entities $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true.

Using this notation, $\exists^{=1}_xP(x)$ means the same than $\exists!_xP(x)$
and $\exists^{=0}_xP(x)$ would mean that there is no such entity $x$.

Thus, what you are looking for would be $\exists^{\le1}_xP(x)$ which could be defined as
$\exists^{\le1}_xP(x) :\Leftrightarrow \exists^{=0}_xP(x) \vee  \exists^{=1}_xP(x)$